# Getting access to target element in parsley custom validators

Tags: parsley.js

I need to get access to the element that is being tested for custom rule in parsley custom validators. In other words, I need something like this:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('uniqueInn', {
    validateString: function(value) 
    {
        $(THE ELEMENT BEING TESTED).closest('table')....;
        // Some code    
    }
    messages: 
    {
        en: 'Custom message'
    }
});
```

Is it possible in parsley ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual argument list for custom validators is: value, requirement, options, instance. That fourth argument is the parsley instance and you can use the `$element` attribute...

PR for better doc always welcome.

Answer (score 3):

For version 2.7.2 you can do this:

```
Parsley.addValidator('uniqueInn', {
    validateString: function(value, requeriment, instance) 
    {
        var element = instance.element; // or instance.$element  
    }
    messages: 
    {
        en: 'Custom message'
    }
});
```